# Purescript: how to parse a query string (in a url/uri)

Tags: purescript

Purescript has a contrib package with `URI.Query` module: https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-uri/8.0.1/docs/URI.Query for parsing it proposes to use `Text.Parsing.Parser`.

Could someone explain by the code example how to parse such query string: `"s=str&i=1&b=true"`

into a record `{s :: String, i :: Int, b :: Maybe Boolean }` (suppose, that the third param `b` is optional, may present or not)

Comment: Do you have any experience with parsers at all?

Comment: No, if I had probably I wodn't ask. -) It is a complex code, needed for completing such a task?

Comment: do you want to parse this as a part of a route? There are quite good packages for parsing complete routes maybe you can go with those? You could probably reuse this [`Routing.Parser](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-routing/10.0.1/docs/Routing.Parser) and start with the `Map String String` you get out of there. Or you can build up a [`Parser`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-parsing/6.0.1/docs/Text.Parsing.Parser#t:Parser) yourself - I guess that was the question from Fyodor: do you know how to deal with parser-combinator libraries?

Comment: https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-uri/8.0.1/docs/URI.Extra.QueryPairs#v:parse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a basic version just using `URI.Extra.QueryPair` with some helpers to parse stuff:

```hs
module Main where

import Prelude

import Data.Either (hush)
import Data.Foldable (lookup)
import Data.Int (fromString)
import Data.Maybe (Maybe(..))
import Effect (Effect)
import Effect.Class.Console (logShow)
import URI.Extra.QueryPairs (QueryPairs(..))
import URI.Extra.QueryPairs as QP
import URI.Query as Q

main :: Effect Unit
main = do
  logShow $ parseQuery "s=str&i=1&b=true"
  logShow $ parseQuery "s=abc&i=42&b=false"
  logShow $ parseQuery "s=str&i=1"

type Query = { s :: String, i :: Int, b :: Maybe Boolean }

parseQuery :: String -> Maybe Query
parseQuery = Q.fromString >>> QP.parse (QP.keyToString >>> pure) (QP.valueToString >>> pure) >>> hush >=> fromPairs

fromPairs :: QueryPairs String String -> Maybe Query
fromPairs (QueryPairs pairs) = do
  s <- join $ lookup "s" pairs
  i <- join (lookup "i" pairs) >>= fromString
  let b = join (lookup "b" pairs) >>= parseBool
  pure { s, i , b}
  where
  parseBool "true" = Just true
  parseBool "false" = Just false
  parseBool _ = Nothing
```

this will output

```
(Just { b: (Just true), i: 1, s: "str" })
(Just { b: (Just false), i: 42, s: "abc" })
(Just { b: Nothing, i: 1, s: "str" })
```

for the examples.

---

The code itself should be rather straight-forward.
Note that `QueryPair String String ~ Array String (Maybe String)` so the *extraction* of values is a bit tedious (`join`)

---

### a version using `routing-duplex`

If you are fine with installing [`purescript-routing-duplex`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-routing-duplex/0.4.1/docs/Routing.Duplex) you can use the parser in there to help you out quite a bit - that's the one I'd use (especially when you probably want to parse routes with parameters anyway):

```hs
module Main where

import Prelude

import Data.Either (hush)
import Data.Maybe (Maybe)
import Effect (Effect)
import Effect.Class.Console (logShow)
import Routing.Duplex as R

main :: Effect Unit
main = do
  logShow $ parseQuery "s=str&i=1&b=true"
  logShow $ parseQuery "s=abc&i=42&b=false"
  logShow $ parseQuery "s=str&i=1"

type Query = { s :: String, i :: Int, b :: Maybe Boolean }

parseQuery :: String -> Maybe Query
parseQuery s = hush $ R.parse parser ("?" <> s)
  where
    parser =
      R.params
        { s: R.string
        , i: R.int
        , b: R.optional <<< R.boolean
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, Routing.Duplex is the best way to go I believe.